# Null reference on MVC 2 Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm writing a MVC 2.0 app with VS2010.  On my Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit machine it runs fine.  On my laptop (Windows 7 Home Premium, 32bit) it is getting a null reference on Server when I call MapPath.

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ContentModel content = new ContentModel();
        content.Content = ContentInterface.GetHtmlContent(Server.MapPath("~"), "Home");
        content.Ads = ContentInterface.GetPartialAds(Server.MapPath("~"), AdCount);
        content.Testimonials = ContentInterface.GetTestimonials();

        return View(content);
    }
```

I have installed MVC 2 via Webinstaller, I reregistered .Net 4 with IIS.  I've confirmed IIS 6 WMI compatibility mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question does seem straightforward, but it's a perplexing problem. Any chance you can post the Exception details along with the source it's reporting in case there's something enlightening there?

Comment: Here is the exception:System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=WeldLink
  StackTrace:
       at WeldLink.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\steve\Documents\WeldLink\WeldLink\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 39
       at WeldLink.Tests.Controllers.HomeControllerTest.Index() in C:\Users\steve\Documents\WeldLink\WeldLink.Tests\Controllers\HomeControllerTest.cs:line 22
  InnerException:

Comment: I would also note, I have other MVC 2 apps that I can develop and run on this same system.

Comment: @Steve - when you update your question, please edit the question to add the additional info, don't post it as a comment as it is much harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: permissions.  I granted Full Control to IUSR and it works now.